How to get doc string for a clojure interface?
Is it possible to get doc-string for a clojure interface or other syntactic entity?
(defn documentedFun "documentedFun is documented" [] 123)
(assert (= (:doc (meta #'documentedFun)) "documentedFun"))

An interface with doc attribute seems syntactically correct:
(definterface ^{:doc "Eq is an interface"} Eq (^{:tell bool} eq [b]) )

but REPL cannot parse doc function applied to Eq.
(doc Eq)


Syntax error compiling var at (/tmp/form-init4163264810453251954.clj:1:1).
Expecting var, but Eq is mapped to interface hello_leiningen.core.Eq


No. Metadata lives on Clojure vars, and interfaces are purely a Java feature. There's nowhere to put the metadata. You could define a protocol instead: a protocol has a var, and defining a protocol also defines an interface.

Java interface can have annotations. This looks as perfect place for docstring. Just need to agree about convention for annotation name.
